# Odoo API write method

Tags: python, odoo

I've read other topics and also the full documentation.

I'm trying to write to a record.
API returns "True", but there is no effect to the field.

```
write_to_db = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'mail.mass_mailing.contact', 'write', [ [the_contact[0]["id"]], { 'tag_ids': the_contact[0]["tag_ids"]}])
```

the_contact[0]["id"] is the id of the contact whose tags I want to change (add a new tag).
the_contact[0]["tag_ids"] contains [1,2] ==> the new list of tags

I'm aware that for one2many and many2many fields I need special syntax:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html
From (0, _, values) ... to (6, _, ids)
But some of those syntax don't even has a place for new values!!! Just options 0 and 1... for the others one have just place to id??? But id is already in the command...

Tried many combinations but none worked.

(Bottom line: I'm a beginner in both Odoo and Python)

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.
The problem was not the syntax.
"tag_ids" in fact are related to res.partner, not to mail.mass_mailing.tag